# Azure Application Gateway Basic - What is the upload limit?

Tags: azure, documentation, azure-application-gateway

I'm struggling with MS documentation to find APP GW Basic Tier Upload Limits.
Limits for App GW are saying that:

```
Maximum file upload size, Standard - 2GB
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#application-gateway-limits

But I don't see limits for Basic Tier.
Shoud I understand that Basic=Standard in the docs ?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I see the Azure APP GW only has the standard and WAF SKU, without the basic SKU. So there is no problem with the limit.

[image]